# Expression resolves to an unused function: CGContext.saveGState

Tags: ios, swift3, cgcontext

I am writing the code to draw image pattern but for the function CGContext.saveGState(), I am receiving error as Expression resolves to an unused function.

can anybody help to write same in swift 3.0. below is the code snippet:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
tempImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height))
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
CGContext.saveGState(context!)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
tempImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height))
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
context?.saveGState()
```

Comment: @Van if my answer is really helpful to you then upvote my answer,so other can also get help from it.

Answer (score 4):

Just call saveGState directly on context object like this:

```
context?.saveGState()
```

Instead of:

```
CGContext.saveGState(context!)
```

Comment: @Van To express gratitude you can select my answer as correct by pressing checkmark.

Comment: @Van It's ok, but I replied two mins earlier :)